# Redirect Old URL to New URL open cart using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, opencart

I want to redirect 301 old url to new url.

my old url is;

`http://www.domainname.com/special`

and new url is;

`http://www.domainname.com/offers`

I tried this code:

`redirect 301 /http://www.domainname.com/special http://www.domainname.com/offers`

But still now it's not redirecting & taking me to the old URL which does'nt exist.

Comment: Try this one ' Redirect 301 /special http://www.domainname.com/offers
'

Comment: Cant you just change the link from the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Redirect 301 /special /offers
```

Second argument of Redirect Directive is the URL Path, it doesn't start with Scheme and hostname.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this and various redirects, I've listed them below:

301 (Permanent) Redirect: Point an entire site to a different URL on a permanent basis. This is the most common type of redirect and is useful in most situations. In this example, we are redirecting to the "example.com" domain:

This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
```

302 (Temporary) Redirect: Point an entire site to a different temporary URL. This is useful for SEO purposes when you have a temporary landing page and plan to switch back to your main landing page at a later date:

This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain

```
Redirect 302 / http://example.com/
```

Redirect index.html to a specific subfolder:

This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder

```
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/newdirectory/
```

Redirect an old file to a new file path:

Redirect old file path to new file path

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Redirect to a specific index page:

Provide Specific Index Page (Set the default handler)

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```