# How to Redirect Old URL to New URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect old URL to new URL but old URL also working because I already submitted old URL. How to fix this problem?

For Example

1. Old URL: http://example.com/p/holi/happy-holi-2019
2. New URL: http://example.com/p/happy-holi-2019

http://example.com/p/holi/happy-holi-2019 to http://example.com/p/happy-holi-2019

Comment: Create htaccess file and place on root folder and `Redirect 301 /p/holi/happy-holi-2019 http://example.com/p/happy-holi-2019`

Comment: *"I want to redirect old url to new url but old url also working"* ... logically, how do you expect that to work? If you go to the old url, do you want it to redirect or not?

Comment: @CD001 I think there should be a `,` in that sentence and OP may have meant '*[...] but for some reason the old URL is still working[...]*', possibly.

Comment: @Script47 ... maybe, but then what do they mean by *"because i already submitted old url"* ? I took that to mean that they wanted the old url to continue working because they're submitted it to Google (or whatever)... I think this question could do with some clarification :)

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770786/redirect-old-url-to-new-url-open-cart-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Redirect 301. `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /p/holi/happy-holi-2019 http://www.example.com/p/happy-holi-2019
```

OR

```
Redirect 301 ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ http://www.example.com/p/$2
```

Comment: i am using .htacess file  RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail.php?cat=$1&post=$2 [L]    i don't understand how to put this code

Comment: You don't actually need to check if you're using `mod_rewrite`, or switch the `RewriteEngine On` if you're just doing a simple `Redirect 301 ...`

Comment: seriously i don't understand. can you help me please

Comment: is correct ?? Redirect 301 p/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+) /p/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)

Comment: @user8274471 - you really need to clarify **exactly** what it is you're trying to do, that chunk of RegEx matching doesn't specifically have anything to do with the original question - and I've still got no idea what you mean by the first sentence, do you want it to redirect the old url or not?

Comment: i want to redirect my old url to new url  still my code in htaccess for detail page  RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail.php?cat=$1&post=$2 [L]     i want redirect old to new but i already submitted old url so i want when user come to old url then user redirect new url

Comment: Did you try this: `Redirect 301 /p/holi/happy-holi-2019 /p/happy-holi-2019`?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by this: '_but i already submitted old url_'?

Comment: i also try this one but its redirect on 404 page. just i want to how to write this line for dynamic url Redirect 301 now its only holi directory  is correct  ?? Redirect 301 p/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+) /p/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)

Comment: my old project running live so my old url working but now requirement to redirect new url  so i want redirect

Comment: If you're already got the rule `RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail.php?cat=$1&post=$2 [L]` that you want to keep, just stick the new rewrite above it (with an `L` flag) `RewriteRule /p/holi/happy-holi-2019 http://www.example.com/p/happy-holi-2019 [R=301,L]` - since they're executed sequentially the old URL will redirect to the new URL which should *then* fall into your general redirect. @user8274471

Comment: Thanks !  to help me

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /p/holi/happy-holi-2019 [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /p/happy-holi-2019 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^p/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail.php?post=$1 [L]
```